# Rails: Install and configure bootstrap on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

how do I make bootstrap work on my custom layouts in rails 6

I have install bootstrap with the `yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js` command and configured my the `..app/config/webpack/environment.js` as follow.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

### ..app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
...

    import 'bootstrap'
    import "../stylesheets/application"
```

### ..app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Everything works fine but when I created another layout file,the layout does not import the bootstrap library.

### ..layout/visitor.html.erb

```
<html>
.....
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
....
```

The bootstrap library is not loaded in this visitor.html.erb layout it is loaded only in the application.html.erb layout file.

how to fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need change

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

to

`<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: I have change the `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` but did not still work

Comment: not in `visitor.html.erb` but i mean in `application.html.erb`

Comment: @foliwe83 your vote down make me try again :)  . but work finally .

Comment: sorry about that